My surrealdb (1.x) migration script
I'm working on a migration script for surrealdb (currently working with 1.x).
Please review and let me know what I should improve.
import Surreal from 'surrealdb.js';
import { config } from 'dotenv-flow';
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

config();

const {
    DB_USER: username,
    DB_PASS: password,
    DB_HOST: host,
    DB_NS: namespace,
    DB_DB: database,
    DB_PORT: port
} = process.env;

const db = new Surreal();

// ESM-compatible way to get the current directory
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

async function connectDB() {
    await db.connect(`${host}:${port}/rpc`, {
        namespace,
        database,
        auth: {
            namespace,
            database,
            username,
            password
        }
    });
}

async function createMigrationHistoryTable() {
    await db.query(`
        DEFINE TABLE migration_history SCHEMAFULL
            PERMISSIONS FULL;
        DEFINE FIELD version ON migration_history TYPE int;
        DEFINE FIELD createdAt ON migration_history TYPE datetime VALUE $before OR time::now();
        DEFINE FIELD migration_name ON migration_history TYPE string;
        DEFINE FIELD up_or_down ON migration_history TYPE string ASSERT $value IN ['up', 'down'];
        DEFINE FIELD table_name ON migration_history TYPE string;
    `);
    console.log('Ensured migration_history table exists.');
}

async function getAppliedMigrations() {
    const [records] = await db.query('SELECT * FROM migration_history ORDER BY version ASC');
    return records.map((r) => ({
        version: r.version,
        up_or_down: r.up_or_down,
        table_name: r.table_name
    }));
}

async function applyMigration(filePath, version, name, direction, tableName) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
    await db.query(content);
    await db.create('migration_history', {
        version,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        migration_name: name,
        up_or_down: direction,
        table_name: tableName
    });
    console.log(`Applied ${direction} migration for table ${tableName}: ${name}`);
}

async function processMigrations(direction = 'up') {
    const baseDir = path.join(__dirname, 'queries');

    const tableDirs = await fs.readdir(baseDir, { withFileTypes: true });
    const appliedMigrations = await getAppliedMigrations();

    for (const dirent of tableDirs) {
        if (!dirent.isDirectory()) continue;

        const tableName = dirent.name;
        const tableDir = path.join(baseDir, tableName);

        const files = await fs.readdir(tableDir);
        const directionMigrations = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(`.${direction}.sql`));
        directionMigrations.sort(); // Ensure files are sorted by version

        const migrationStates = new Map(
            appliedMigrations
                .filter((m) => m.table_name === tableName)
                .map((m) => [m.version, m.up_or_down])
        );

        for (const file of directionMigrations) {
            const [versionStr] = file.split('_');
            const version = parseInt(versionStr, 10);

            if (
                (direction === 'up' &&
                    (!migrationStates.has(version) || migrationStates.get(version) === 'down')) ||
                (direction === 'down' && migrationStates.get(version) === 'up')
            ) {
                const filePath = path.join(tableDir, file);
                await applyMigration(filePath, version, file, direction, tableName);
            } else {
                console.log(`Skipping ${file} as it is not applicable for the current direction.`);
            }
        }
    }
}

async function resetMigrations() {
    const baseDir = path.join(__dirname, 'queries');
    const appliedMigrations = await getAppliedMigrations();

    const lastMigrationByTable = appliedMigrations.reduce((acc, migration) => {
        const { table_name, version, up_or_down } = migration;
        if (!acc[table_name] || acc[table_name].version < version) {
            acc[table_name] = { version, up_or_down };
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});

    for (const [tableName, { version, up_or_down }] of Object.entries(lastMigrationByTable)) {
        if (up_or_down === 'up') {
            const tableDir = path.join(baseDir, tableName);
            const file = `${version}_*.down.sql`; // Matches the format with the version
            const filePath = path.join(tableDir, file);

            console.log(`Rolling back table ${tableName} using ${file}`);
            await applyMigration(filePath, version, file, 'down', tableName);
        } else {
            console.log(`Skipping table ${tableName} as it is already rolled back.`);
        }
    }

    await db.query("DELETE FROM migration_history WHERE up_or_down = 'up';");
    console.log('Cleared "up" migrations from migration history.');

    await processMigrations('up');
}

function formatTimestamp() {
    const now = new Date();
    return `${now.getFullYear()}${(now.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}${now.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}_${now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}${now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}${now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

async function createMigrationFiles(tableName, description = 'migration') {
    const tableDir = path.join(__dirname, 'queries', tableName);

    await fs.mkdir(tableDir, { recursive: true });

    const files = await fs.readdir(tableDir);
    const migrationNumbers = files
        .map((file) => parseInt(file.split('_')[0], 10))
        .filter(Number.isInteger)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);

    const latestMigrationNumber = migrationNumbers.length ? migrationNumbers.pop() : 0;
    const newMigrationNumber = latestMigrationNumber + 1;
    const timestamp = formatTimestamp();
    const formattedDescription = description.replace(/\s+/g, '_');

    const upFilePath = path.join(
        tableDir,
        `${newMigrationNumber}_${timestamp}_${formattedDescription}.up.sql`
    );
    const downFilePath = path.join(
        tableDir,
        `${newMigrationNumber}_${timestamp}_${formattedDescription}.down.sql`
    );

    await fs.writeFile(
        upFilePath,
        `-- Write your SQL migration up query here for ${tableName}`,
        'utf8'
    );
    await fs.writeFile(
        downFilePath,
        `-- Write your SQL migration down query here for ${tableName}`,
        'utf8'
    );

    console.log(`Created new migration files: ${upFilePath} and ${downFilePath}`);
}

(async function () {
    try {
        await connectDB();
        await createMigrationHistoryTable();

        const command = process.argv[2];

        if (command === 'up') {
            await processMigrations('up');
        } else if (command === 'down') {
            await processMigrations('down');
        } else if (command === 'reset') {
            await resetMigrations();
        } else if (command === 'create') {
            const tableName = process.argv[3];
            const description = process.argv[4] || 'migration';
            if (!tableName) {
                console.error('Please specify the table name for creating migrations.');
                process.exit(1);
            }
            await createMigrationFiles(tableName, description);
        } else {
            console.log('Usage: node migrate.js [up|down|reset|create :table-name :description]');
        }

        await db.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Migration error:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();



The code is quite good, the only thing missing really are comments.
Like this here:
const migrationNumbers = files
    .map((file) => parseInt(file.split('_')[0], 10))
    .filter(Number.isInteger)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);

And maybe slightly better logging, provide a stacktrace to the user etc.
